# Parsing PickList values from AutotaskAPI

Tags: python, python-2.7, suds

I'm trying to match the number values I get from a query to AutotaskAPI with the picklist tables that match that number to an actual definition in words. With the following code snippet:

```
for entity in entities:
    for key, value in enumerate(self.queueCode["PicklistValues"]["PickListValue"][0]["Value"]):
        print value
```

Which return all the Tickets in the system along with their number values, but the `for key, value in enumerate(self.queueCode["PicklistValues"]["PickListValue"][0]["Value"])` is what I was using to get the picklist values. So this print would return "30098742" from:

```
(PickListValue){
   Value = "30098742"
   Label = "BF Onsite"
   IsDefaultValue = False
   SortOrder = 44
   parentValue = None
   IsActive = True
   IsSystem = False
```

How can I get all Picklist Values and corresponding Labels?

UPDATE:

The following code will do what I want in terms of getting the number value of `Value`, however, I'm not iterating over all the Picklists, so in my ex, [0] is not going [0],[1],[2], etc., which would give me values of all the Picklists.

```
for key, value in enumerate(self.queueCode["PicklistValues"]["PickListValue"][0]["Value"]):
         print value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `"Value"` entry in the dictionary is a string representation of a number, when you `enumerate` it you're actually just iterating over the characters in the string. The `enumerate` object in your example would give you the indices of each character, and the characters, like this:

```
>>> list(enumerate("30098742"))
[(0, '3'), (1, '0'), (2, '0'), (3, '9'), (4, '8'), (5, '7'), (6, '4'), (7, '2')]
```

If the first PickList you want is `self.queueCode["PicklistValues"]["PickListValue"][0]`, then instead of getting that explicitly, you probably need to enumerate over the underlying list of PickLists; something like:

```
for idx, plist in enumerate(self.queueCode["PicklistValues"]["PickListValue"]):
    print "PickList with index {} has value {} and label {}".format(
        idx, plist["Value"], plist["Label"]
    )
```

As an aside, I wouldn't advise writing `for key, value in enumerate(sequence)` because the "key" is actually not a key, but an ordinal number counting the items you're enumerating. In this case, it corresponds to an index, so I'd probably use a name like `i` or `idx` in the loop.